# Define title to a matplotlib table

Tags: python, matplotlib, datatable, title

I have a table generated by matplotlib, and I want to insert a title for it. Do anyone know how to do it?

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
spec2 = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=3, figure=fig  )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(spec2[0, 0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(spec2[0, 1])
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.axis('off')

table_data=[
["Ni_Tot ", "NN", "2.5%" , round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.025),3)],
["N. of Samples", count,  "5%" , round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.05),3)],
["Minimum", round(min(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3), "25%" , round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.25),3)],
["Maximum", round(max(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3), "Median", round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.5),3)],
["Average", round(statistics.mean(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].apply(pd.to_numeric)),3),"75%", round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.75),3)],
["Variance", round(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].var(),2), "95%", round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.95),3)],
["Std Deviation", round(df['NN_Ni_Tot'].std(),2),"97.5%", round(df.NN_Ni_Tot.quantile(0.975),3)],]


table = ax1.table(cellText=table_data, loc='center', cellLoc='center')
table.set_fontsize(14)
table.scale(1.5,1.4)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P27Vu.png

Comment: In the future please make sure to provide an MRE [(Minimal, Reproducible Example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and to make sure that it actually runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
ax.set_title("Your title")
```

[Relevant documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
ax1.set_title("Your title")
```

The code line above worked, but the title was positioned in the middle of the table, overlapping the data. So I had to ajust it manually

```
ax1.set_title("NN_NI", fontsize=8, y=1.8, pad=-14)
```